# Getting data from non connected relationship Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

The title may be a little misleading i'm not sure what to call it,

I have a model called user which has 3 relationships

Image belongs To User -> has many images

Profile Belongs to User -> has one profile

Views Belongs to user -> has  many views

so what i am trying to do is

```
return Views::with('User')->where('viewed_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->paginate(20)
```

which get's all the views and the user assosiated with it, i would also like to get the data from image, but image belongs to User and no Views

how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to expand your `with()` statement, using dot notation, to include the relationship, as long as the relationship is set up within User (this is assuming that the related images method is called `Images()` within the User model):

```
return Views::with('User', 'User.Images')
    ->where('viewed_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
    ->paginate(20);
```

Comment: would you mind linking the documentation for that i cant seem to find it

Comment: No problem, you'll find it under Eager Loading: 

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading